# How to animate ExtJs window from top right of browser?

Tags: extjs4.2

```
this.changePasswordWin = Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
                title: "Change Password",
                modal: true,
                closeAction: 'hide',
                animateTarget: Ext.getDoc(),
                items: [ this.textfieldPanel ],
                dockedItems: [{
                    xtype: 'toolbar',
                    dock: 'bottom',
                    border: false,

                }]
            });
```

The above code is working fine with animate from top left. But i want this to animate from top right. Help me! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

set x: screen.width. It will set the position of the window to the right corner. if it is not exactly minus the position based on the browser screen.